# Exclude a device from install of an android apk

Tags: android, installation, apk, screen-resolution

Is there a way to not allow a particular device to install an android apk?

I'm having some problems on controlling some layouts on a program when installed in Motorola Artix (Atrix has a hi-res and mine only considers o so I want to exclude the device.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Exclude a device? I could understand excluding some older devices but to exclude a new device is a bad idea. It would be better that you dedicate time to making your device compatible with new devices. There is a lot of documentation for this on the Android site.

Perhaps you should post code for your layout and the issue in order to get input on if you can make it better in order to work for the device.

DONT TRY TO EXCLUDE IT THOUGH... The google dashboard has statistics now on user data and you can see the different screen sizes and OS versions using you app.

Just my 2 cents. Good luck.

Comment: Yep, already found out about how to support multiple screens, but 'twas too late to implement based from previous codes. I was thinking along the lines of a condition if not this certain device or something then halt install and display a notice that the dev will handle this and get back to the user for an update.

Comment: @IsisBlack, Very sloppy. Also, you cant halt installation of your own app if the app which has the code to halt installation is not installed. :o)

Comment: LOL. Right right. It's still better to just specify the support then.

Comment: Im not sure how elaborate the layout but are you sure you cant just support it? Perhaps post some code and see if other have input on possible changes.